# Constructing separate classes (normalizing?)

Tags: java, class

I am writing an app where a user can log into which accesses (for now, at least) a mysql database server.  I am thinking that the way I should do this is to create separate classes for each portion; example:  I have a main window which will house buttons for what a user wants to do, and classes for each button.ActionEvent.  I am thinking that by separating my classes in this way, it becomes 1) easier to work with in the long run, and 2) easier to port (i.e. Windows GUI classes, Android classes).  Am I doing this right?

- Current classes;
- MainWindow (contains buttons for login, logout, retrieve asset list, retrieve current work orders)
- Login
- Logout (shoud I combine this with Login?)
- AssestList (a query - returns a table)
- WorkOrderList (a query - returns an editable JPanel)

Comment: Please go through the Help Center if you have doubts about how to ask a question and what to ask about.

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad for this site. You will get a great response here when you start coding, get stuck, then come back and and ask a specific question about a problem in that specific piece of code. Best of luck with the project. Oh and to point you in the right direction you are on the right track with separating out your concerns. Check out MVC and consider writing a REST Based API to access your DB data. That way you will be able to write mulitple clients on differing platforms to access that data.

Comment: Thanks Rob, and usually when it's a problem with the actual code, the QnA here helps me work through my "coding" issues.  That's what makes Stack so useful to me.  The current problem is that I want to know if this is the way I should be writing the classes (as separate), and I can't find the answer on google.  I think the value of coders who typically provide answers could simply say yes (separate), or no (combine). - Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Classes are nouns. Not verbs. `AssetList` is a noun - a class that represents something tangible. `Login` and `Logout` are certainly not...

Comment: @BoristheSpider - What you are saying is essential to me.  If I understand you, since the Login button is in a JDialog,  the class should be named LoginDialog, and since the logout button is simply a call to close the connection, it should be an ActionEvent inside of the main window.  Did I get that?

Comment: @LeftysLoft. I would suggest, write the simplest code that does the job and post the code on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer has no ambition of being anything more than a cursory glance at the MVC pattern and how it may help you.*

I second Rob Kielty's advice that you should have a look at the MVC pattern at this stage in your learning. It will help you structure your code and improve readability, modularity and reusability. This is especially relevant to you if you plan on porting your application to Android.

The essential idea is to keep the logic of your app (the **C**[ontroller] in MVC, the hidden part/classes) **separate/uncoupled** from the UI classes (**V**[iew], platform dependent). If you have classes that are used mainly to hold data or state, we call them model classes (**M**[odel], like User, Stock, …).

- Controller classes should have little to ideally no dependency on your UI classes.
- Model classes should be independent and thus platform-agnostic.
- View classes (UI) will depend on both controller and model classes but also on the UI framework (AWT, Swing, JavaFX, web frameworks, ... ).

**Simplistic example**:

With that in mind, imagine that, as your application starts, you want to to identify a user. At this stage, the Controller is in charge and displays a login dialog(/window/webpage). The controller remains into a stand-by state, waiting for user action. A hit on the 'Submit' button of that dialog will be processed directly by the controller and may result in the user being taken to the next stage/dialog (successful login) or in a UI update of the login dialog indicating a failed authentication attempt. It is fundamental to keep UI concerns separate from logic ones, ie. a hit on 'Submit' sends an event to the controller or calls a method but the actual logic work is not done in the login dialog.

Note that no amount of explaining and reading will replace hard won experience though. So don't be afraid of revisiting your copy again and again. And beware if you're a perfectionist at heart, the battle is already lost. HTH

Comment: Excellent feedback.  Thank you all. I would +1 all of if I could. I am researching MVC right now, as this seems to be just what I was looking for. It may have not been the right place to ask for some, but it was to me. In asking a question which seem (s/ed) too broad, I have learned about more appropriate class naming (nouns, not verbs), and a clear path for how to make my code easier to read and understand.  This, in turn, makes for better structure on my end and will make my program be better formatted, as will my actual 'coding' questions.
Thank you. - Today I am better than yesterday.